# Mapping object property (column name) from Array of Objects to a row and header(column)Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-ui

I am currently working on mapping an array of object (originally created from localStorage) to a table using Materia-UI Table.

I want to map all the specific column name in a Table Cell

For example, I have an array (it's not in a file)

```
var array = [{ date: '2019-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM' }, 
{ date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM'}, 
{ date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM' }, { date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM' }, { date: '2017-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM' }, 
{ date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM' }]
```

I want to create a table using that library or you can use th tr or td tags, since it works well with React (picture down below) For example all the name that has column name `date` will go to Date, and `driver_name` will go to Driver.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an initial attempt to start from?

Comment: Initially I created a sub array for the columns  but it did not work out since it will give me " " and , with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `array` is you defined array.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Driver</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {array.map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
           <td>{element.date}</td>
           <td>{element.driver_name}</td>
          </tr>
        )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think this should work ツ

Comment: It did not work, it gave me an error '' Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression''

Comment: You aren't returning from your map. You will need to give the `tr` a `key`.

Comment: so I have tr my key fro say (element, tr => ...) correct?

Comment: arrow function adds return automatically but you are right we should add a unique key in ```tr```

Comment: No it doesn't. Using `()` returns automatically. You used `{}` so you must return.

Comment: This worked pretty well, and I got it to interact with brush on graph. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, also thank you [@Brian Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381601/brian-thompson) you were right return was needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Material-UI with Card Component (you can also skip the Card component), you can use a code like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import {
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TablePagination,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';

var rides = [{ date: '2019-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM' },
{ date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM'},
{ date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM' }, { date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM' }, { date: '2017-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM' },
{ date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM' }];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {},
  content: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  nameContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  actions: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  },

  title: {
    flex: '1 1 100%',
  },
  table: {
    '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
      padding: 4,
    },
  },
}));

const RideTable = props => {
  //const { rides, ...rest } = props;
  const { className, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);


  const handlePageChange = (event, page) => {
    setPage(page);
  };

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = event => {
    setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      {...rest}
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
    >
      <CardContent className={classes.content}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            className={classes.title}
            variant="h6"
            id="tableTitle"
          >
            Rides
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
        <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Driver</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rides.map((ride, index) => (
              <TableRow
                className={classes.tableRow}
                hover
                key={'ride-' + index}
              >
                <TableCell>{ride.date}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{ride.driver_name}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
        <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={rides.length}
          onChangePage={handlePageChange}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleRowsPerPageChange}
          page={page}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};


export default RideTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Array.map() function,
Array.map(callback) will return an array with the return values of the callback executed with the array contents as parameters:

you can make a function that creates the html for a row smth like

```
function dataToTableRow(data){
    return `<tr><td>${data.date}</td><td>${data.driver_name}</td></tr>`
}
```

giving this function as callback to the array.map:

```
const rowsHtml = (array.map(dataToTableRow))
```

will return an array of the strings that contains the HTML for each row you can put them all in one string by doing

```
const tableBody = rowsHtml.join("")
```

now you have html for all the rows in tableBody all you need to do is to make your own header etc...

Comment: This isn't a good approach in react. The table elements need to be JSX, not string literals. In plain javascript this may work, but react won't render this as HTML, it will be escaped and printed as a string.

Comment: That is true, however given how litte information OP has given i wasn't immediately aware that he is looking for a copy & paste solution for react (eventhough i should have bothered to extrapolate) but rather focused on explaining  the concept of Array.map().